# "Protagonist in" or "protagonist of"?

Tags: prepositions, word-usage, nuance

If I were to write an intro for a protagonist in say, a game, would I say he/she is the "protagonist *of* [title]" or the "protagonist *in* [title]"? Or does it matter?

Comment: Have you bothered to look in any dictionaries, which give examples of usage, such as [ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/protagonist?q=protagonist), [Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/protagonist), [Chambers](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=protagonist&title=21st), [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/protagonist)?  ***Please*** do some basic research of your own before asking questions here, as indicated in the Help & FAQ.

Comment: Hmm. My question wasn't _really_ directed specifically to the word "protagonist", but more of the _article_ usage "in" and "of". I wanted to know exactly _why_ the articles would weigh one over the other. But eh. Whatever.

Comment: Then please edit your question to ask exactly what you do want to know.

Comment: @ Jacedc: I think it's a good question. The long and short of it for your purposes is probably *it doesn't matter*. Personally I think I'd choose ***in*** for a game, but that might be because overall I don't rate games so highly. I might be more likely to choose ***of*** if it was, say, *Hamlet is the protagonist **of** the play (of the same name! :)*. Or without the repetition, I'd say *Prospero is the protagonist **of** The Tempest*. Preliminary checks with Google suggest that *on average* others do the same.

Comment: Thanks @FumbleFingers and @ TrevorD, I understand, I should have been more specific but I wanted to get straight to the point. But it's noted. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't understand the downvotes, and I *really* don't think this kind of distinction could easily be found by "basic research" with dictionaries/grammar guides. Look at [the actual usage pattern](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20protagonist%20in,a%20protagonist%20of&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)...

[image]

Note that the pattern for [definite article usage](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20protagonist%20in,the%20protagonist%20of&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) is slightly different...

[image]

All that accords with my own gut feelings - there's not much to choose between them, but overall, ***of*** is more common (*particularly* when the "protagonist" is ***the*** only one).

I think that's because when you say someone is ***of*** somewhere, there are more connotations that they *represent* that place (or movie, or game, or whatever). If you say they're ***in*** it, I get more the sense that they just *happen* to be there (as well as being in other movies/games, maybe).

But it all gets a bit vague when you consider very closely related contexts. For me at least, if there's anything at all to choose between...

> 1: [He's the lead singer **in** [someband1]](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22the%20lead%20singer%20in%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)
>    and
>    2: [He's the lead singer **of** [someband2]](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22the%20lead%20singer%20in%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22the%20lead%20singer%20of%22&oq=%22the%20lead%20singer%20of%22&gs_l=serp.3...90899.91735.1.92031.4.0.4.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.23.psy-ab..8.0.0.PLx_vc78vFE&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.50165853,d.d2k,pv.xjs.s.en_US.seW1cfrvSKg.O&fp=c74fb9c2dbf5756c&biw=1369&bih=911)

...I think I'd say either *someband1* is less famous than *someband2*, or for some other reason the role of "lead singer" is less significant in the context of what *someband1* is all about.

---

In short, it's all *highly* subjective. There's not really any grammatical issue involved - just idiomatic preference, which is gradually shifting from ***of*** to ***in*** overall. My opinions on possible distinctions in meaning (actually, just "almost imperceptible nuances") are just that - opinions.

Of course, other prepositions can be used. ***From***, for example. And *lead singers* are often ***out of*** [someband] these days (but probably not *protagonists* so often). I don't feel quite so comfortable with that one, but I can't argue with the fact that it's increasingly common.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I wanted to know. In writing articles I try to be a structurally neat as possible and I was curious. Thanks!

Comment: @Jacedc: Apparently *four* people have closevoted as "General Reference", which baffles me. I honestly don't see how you could hope to "look up" the "unambiguously correct" answer to this one. I could have drivelled on some more about possible nuances in closely-related contexts, but at the end of the day all that would be more opinions. You can make up your own mind whether to use **in** or **of** if one sounds "better" to you than the other. Neither choice could meaningfully be called "wrong", but it's a racing cert some nouns will favour one more than the other, *on average*.

Answer (score 0):

"In" suggests area, place, or context - http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/in (Items # 1 & 2).

"Of" suggests motivation or reason - http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/of (Item #3).

Comment: I'm not sure there's much connection between *dying **of** hunger* and being a *protagonist **of/in** a game*.